# How to extract table data like excel table cells and table row data from PPT in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am currently parsing a PPTX document using apache poi and able to extract images, embedded OLE Objects from ppt slide XSLFSlide but dont know how to extract embedded xls tables from the slide. I need help try to parse and read embedded xls tables in a PPT Slide.

Answer (score 1):

From the POI docs at https://poi.apache.org/components/poifs/embeded.html

> Files embedded in PowerPoint - PowerPoint does not normally store embedded files in the OLE2 layer. Instead, they are held within records of the main PowerPoint file. See the [HSLF Tutorial](https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#OLE) for how to retrieve embedded OLE objects from a presentation

> Opening embedded files - All of the POIDocument classes (HSSFWorkbook, HSLFSlideShow, HWPFDocument and HDGFDiagram) can either be opened from a POIFSFileSystem, or from a specific directory within a POIFSFileSystem. So, to open embedded files, simply locate the appropriate DirectoryNode that represents the subdirectory of interest, and pass this + the overall POIFSFileSystem to the constructor.

> I you want to extract the textual contents of the embedded file, then open the appropriate POIDocument, and then pass this to the extractor class, instead of simply passing the POIFSFilesystem to the extractor.

And from the [HSLF Tutorial](https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#OLE)

```java
for (HSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
    if (shape instanceof OLEShape) {
        OLEShape ole = (OLEShape) shape;
        HSLFObjectData data = ole.getObjectData();
        String name = ole.getInstanceName();
        if ("Worksheet".equals(name)) {
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(data.getData());
        } else if ("Document".equals(name)) {
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(data.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You can use [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) to abstract yourself from the underlying data format (eg [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) vs [XSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html)).

Eg:

```java
if ("Worksheet".equals(name)) {
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(data.getInputStream());
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   for (Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator() ; rowIterator.hasNext(); ) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/file.xlsx"))) {
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inStream);
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator() ; rowIterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Row row = rowIterator.next();
      for (Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); cellIterator.hasNext(); )  {
         Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
         switch (cell.getCellType()) 
         {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
               System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
               break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
               System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
               break;
            ...   
         }
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Comment: To clarify a bit, I am currently parsing a PPTX file and reading XLS table from one of the slides, Can you please let know how to parse a ppt slide and read xls table from it